# When I use 'While' in C#, I don't wanna print the last calculation

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I have a question about using 'while' in C#. I made a loop using 'while', but I don't know how to make it, and it did not print the last calculation.

Code:

```cs
if (obj.ControlCommand == 2)
{
    try
    {
        while (obj.LiftHeight > sendMessage.LiftHeight)
        {
             sendMessage.LiftStatus = 12;
             sendMessage.LiftHeight += 0.1f;
             Thread.Sleep(1000);

             if (sendMessage.LiftHeight >= obj.LiftHeight)
             {
                 sendMessage.LiftStatus = 0;
                 sendMessage.LiftHeight = obj.LiftHeight;
             }
        }
```

When I set obj.LiftHeight to 2.95 for instance, it will increase 0.1 per sec.., but sendMessage.LiftHeight shown '... , 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 2.95, 2.95 ... '. I want to make ' ..., 2.8, 2.9, 2.95, 2.95 ... ' What should I change to make it like that?

```cs
while (obj.LiftHeight < sendMessage.LiftHeight)
{
    sendMessage.LiftStatus = 12;
    sendMessage.LiftHeight -= 0.1f;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    if (sendMessage.LiftHeight <= obj.LiftHeight)
    {
       sendMessage.LiftStatus = 0;
       sendMessage.LiftHeight = obj.LiftHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no code here that prints anything, so its unclear what you are asking

Comment: @MichaelRandall I think the question is worded somewhat badly, but to me it's clear what he is asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I see, the problem lies in the place you are incrementing `sendMessage.LiftHeight`. You should check whether it will go too high before incrementing. Change your code to

```
if (obj.ControlCommand == 2)
{
    try
    {
        while (obj.LiftHeight > sendMessage.LiftHeight)
        {          
             if (sendMessage.LiftHeight + 0.1f >= obj.LiftHeight)
             {
                 sendMessage.LiftStatus = 0;
                 sendMessage.LiftHeight = obj.LiftHeight;
             }
             else
             {
                 sendMessage.LiftStatus = 12;
                 sendMessage.LiftHeight += 0.1f;
                 Thread.Sleep(1000);
             }
        }
```